# How do I make decision/ interpret results from the feature coefficients when their signs change in Logistic Regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, classification, feature-selection

I have a Logistic Regression model. There are around 10 features, 3 of which are basically highly correlated (Lets call them x_5, x_6, x_7). In fact x_5 + x_6 = x_7. But they are all kind of important in the business sense.

I did a log transformation on the data, and since there are quite a number of zeros, I also added 1 to all data. That means:

1) x_5 + x_6 = x_7

2) I did log(1 + x_5), log(1 + x_6) and log(1 + x_7) (and also other features)

And then I fit a Logistic Regression in different cases, and checked the coefficients.(Lets call them beta_5, beta_6, beta_7 for x_5, x_6, x_7 respectively). The cases are summarized below. (zero means I omit the variable, i.e. in case 2 I omitted x_7)

[image]

There are something that I find confused.

1) The signs of beta_5 and beta_6 change from case 1 to case 2. I understand this is becoz of the multicollinearity issue. But does it affect the predictability of my Logistic Model?

2) The value of beta_7 drops quite significantly from case 1 to case 3. Does case 3 explain better the importance of x_7?

3) Based on this findings, which case should I use? Or how should I make the decision?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you have the governing equation x5+x6 = x7, then you may drop one of them from the beginning.
To be confident about final solution, you could apply [regularization using Lasso](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html) to know which feature(s) could be removed.